# Java SDK HyperLedger Fabric

Tags: java, api, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am new using the HyperLedger Fabric Java SDK. I have been using the fabcar example as a starting point. I would like to hook up the application to a rest API, where users can submit a transaction to the blockchain but I am having a hard time finding a good resource for this. the example I am following is here: https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-application-using-fabric-java-sdk. From this example, I am simply building the application and then copying the jar file into various classes to invoke the chain and query the chain ,etc. I am a little confused by this approach. Is this the standard for using HyperLedger fabric, all done from the command line like this, and are the logs that are outputted the actual blockchain? Are there any other resources out there that can help me with this concept?

Answer (score 0):

I also experience like you. Before you start to learn how to code Fabric Java SDK, you need to understand all of the components and processes of Hyperledger Fabric. Then, you download the Fabric Java SDK from [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java). Please read the [read.me](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java/blob/master/README.md) carefully. After you created the Maven project and imported the latest Fabric Java SDK, then you import the sample project files from this [folder](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java/tree/master/src/test/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/sdkintegration). I recommend you to test the project file name [End2endIT.java](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/sdkintegration/End2endIT.java) first.

For your info, you need to run the script to create the container in Docker before you run [End2endIT.java](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/sdkintegration/End2endIT.java). The script files are in this [folder](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java/tree/master/src/test/fixture/sdkintegration). When you enter that folder you need to run the script in the command line with `.\fabric.sh start` to create the container in Docker. There have various commands using in different situations. Please read [fabric.sh](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java/blob/master/src/test/fixture/sdkintegration/fabric.sh) file carefully.